# How can I extend the date display of the Gantt chart using DHTMLX Gantt?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, codeigniter, dhtmlx

I am creating a planner and I included a gantt chart in it. My problem is I am trying to create a schedule that start in March 31, 2016 and it will ends in April 15, 2016. But my problem is my graph doesn't display the next month.

My process is, by default my graph will load the current month with its first and last day and displayed by days.

Here's my sample code:

```
//get first and last day of current month
var parsed = Date.parse("today");
var firstOfMonth = new Date(parsed.getFullYear(),parsed.getMonth(), 1);
var lastOfMonth = new Date(parsed.getFullYear(),parsed.getMonth()+1, 0);
var f_firstOfMonth = firstOfMonth.toString("yyyy-MM-dd");
var f_lastOfMonth = lastOfMonth.toString("yyyy-MM-dd");

//assign to the empty gantt
$(".mygantt").dhx_gantt({
    data: '',
    start_date: f_firstOfMonth,
    end_date: f_lastOfMonth,
    scale_height: 50,
    scale_unit: "day",          
});
```

Can you help me with this? I am using [this example here](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/samples/01_initialization/01_basic_init.html).

Comment: Follow these links: first check [Samples link](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/samples/). Than choose [03 Scales](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/samples/03_scales/). There is many options you can use for needed purpose. I recommend dinamic scale, year scale, auto resize scale, custom scale or even zoom to fit scale (probably your favorite IMHO). Check the code of any of those (F12 in Google Chrome) or check related topics on their [forums](http://forum.dhtmlx.com/index.php).

Answer (score 0):

So you want to display current month by default, and then adjust displayed range as new tasks are added?

Timeline range can be defined by [start_date](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/api__gantt_start_date_config.html) and [end_date](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/api__gantt_end_date_config.html) configs which can be changed dynamically, these changes will be applied after a full redraw of a gantt.

So what you can do:

- Add a handler for [onBeforeGanttRender](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/api__gantt_onbeforeganttrender_event.html)  event, which is fired before
  full redraw of the gantt. It is a good entry point for such settings.
- Inside the handler you can get the date range of tasks using [gantt.getSubtaskDates](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/api__gantt_getsubtaskdates.html) and update start_date/end_date configs accordingly
- Each time user adds, updates or removes task you'll need to trigger
  full redraw of gantt
- You don't need start_date/end_date configs during the data
  loading, since they will filter out tasks that located
  outside the current month

Here is a complete demo http://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/snippet/7d86e912